# Transfer huge files to new server through FTP

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, file-transfer, wget

I have a dedicated server in Germany with 120GB data, since I have bought a new dedicated server in U.S, I would like to transfer all the files to new server through FTP connection, to achieve this I'm able using the following wget command in my new server:

```
nohup wget -m --user=myusername --password=mypassowrd ftp://ftp.mysite.xyz > wget_backup_transfer_log.log 2>&1 &
```

I would like to know is there any better way to do it and is the above command stable regarding to these huge files data?

Thanks in Advance...

*P.S Both servers running CentOS 6.5*

Comment: Is your heart set on FTP?  I'd probably use `rsync` (no doubt through ssh).  With the large files throw a `--partial` option in there so it can recover gracefully if it fails.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but related to your operation: remember to take hashes (`sha1sum filename`) of your files before and after the transfer, to make sure no transmission errors crept up into any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most better ways to do it involve *not using FTP*. Instead, the preferred method would be **rsync**:

```
rsync -avPh mysite.xyz:/home /oldhome
```

Either the source or the destination can be remote (`host:/path`). The transfer happens over SSH, so you only need the `rsync` tool on both servers, and the transfer is encrypted (which is wise).

rsync automatically detects which files were modified/added/missing, so it's safe to interrupt and restart if needed. The basic options are `-a -v`, but you should also add `-P -h` to allow resuming a large file mid-transfer.

(Also maybe `-h -H -A -X` to preserve various additional metadata like ACLs or xattrs.)

Comment: If you run the command in "screen" you can disconnect from the terminal and then reconnect whenever you want.

Comment: @ChristianIsaksson So you mean using `screen rsync ...`?

Comment: My linux skills are .. meh.. but i know that you can run screen first alone, that will create and put you inside a screen. Then you have "ctrl-a d" to disconnect from it, screen -r will re-attach it. You can also open a new terminal inside the screen with "ctrl-a c". Using "ctrl-a #" where # is a number you can switch between terminals.

Comment: @Ali: You even mention `nohup` in your own post...